# why python says Expected ")" when i am creating variable in python?

Tags: python

all of the code is on my github link is here: https://github.com/xPuszek/xPuszek/tree/main
and the error is here:

```
    'bezczynny' : engine.Animation([
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_00.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_01.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_02.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_03.png"),
    ]),
    'chodzi' : engine.Animation([
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_04.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_05.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_06.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_07.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_08.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_09.png")
    ])
```

it says: "Expected ")" Pylance [34, 17]
i cannot post all of the code here because stackoverflow says it too much code

Comment: We don't want all of your code, just a [mre].

Comment: i dont know what is this

Comment: Read [tour] and [ask]. You should be posting a [mre], _not_ a link to your code, _not_ a meaningless fragment with no indication if where the error is.

Comment: So follow the link and read about it. Then [edit] the question to provide it, not just an offsite link.

Comment: ok i am going to try

Comment: `player_animations` looks like it should be a dictionary not a tuple. As such you should be setting like `player_animations = {` not `player_animations = (`

Answer (score 3):

it looks like player animations should be a dictionary as such you should be defining it with curly braces not round ones

```py
player_animations = {
    'bezczynny': engine.Animation([
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_00.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_01.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_02.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_03.png"),
    ]),
    'chodzi': engine.Animation([
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_04.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_05.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_06.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_07.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_08.png"),
        pygame.image.load("ogurek/player_09.png"),
    ])
}
```

Comment: Also in your original code the reason you are getting expected `)` is because you didnt actually close the player animations with a closing `)` but even if you had you proably wanted a dict